# Отправка сообщения с приложенным изображением в ВК

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api

Я пытаюсь отправить сообщение с изображением в виде приложения. В документации в VkApi сказано, что при отправлении POST-запроса я получаю JSON-объект с полями `server, hash, photo` где `photo` также является JSON-объектом.

```
session = vk.AuthSession(app_id=app_id, user_login=user_login,
                         user_password=user_password, scope=scope)
vkapi = vk.API(session)
vkapi.access_token = access_token

data = vkapi.photos.getMessagesUploadServer(user_id=target_id)


upload_url = data["upload_url"]
files = {'photo': open("hello.jpg", 'rb')}

response = requests.post(upload_url, files=files)
result = json.loads(response.text)


vkapi.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(server=result["server"],
                               photo=result["photo"],
                               hash=result["hash"])

imageID = json.loads(result["photo"])[0]["photo"]

attachment = "photo{}_{}".format(target_id, imageID)
print(attachment)

vkapi.messages.send(user_id=target_id,
                    message="randomTextMessage",
                    attachment=attachment)
```

Используя этот код у меня получается отправить текстовое сообщение, но картинка в приложении не появляется изображения.

Comment: Попробуйте `files = {'photo': ('hello.jpg', open("hello.jpg", 'rb'))}`, поможет — напишу развёрнутый ответ

Comment: @andreymal Нет, результат не изменился.  Я разобрался в чем проблема и как ни странно разницы между files = {'photo': ('hello.jpg', open("hello.jpg", 'rb'))} и files = {'photo': open("hello.jpg", 'rb')} нет никакой.

Answer (score 1):

В конечном итоге я разобрался, `image_id` которое нужно было добавить в `attachment` это не то, что мы получаем из JSON-объекта полсе POST-запроса, а то, что мы получаем из поля `id` после вызова `vkapi.photos.saveMessagesPhoto`.
Так что это должно выглядеть следующим образом:

```
messageContentDirectory = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "\\folder\\"
data = vkapi.photos.getMessagesUploadServer(user_id=target_id)


upload_url = data["upload_url"]
files = {'photo': open("hello.jpg", 'rb')}

response = requests.post(upload_url, files=files)
result = json.loads(response.text)

uploadResult = vkapi.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(server=result["server"],
                                              photo=result["photo"],
                                              hash=result["hash"])

vkapi.messages.send(user_id=target_id,
                    message="randomTextMessage",
                    attachment=uploadResult[0]["id"])
```