# Как отправлять картинки к сообщению с помощью vk_api?

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Делаю бота, надо научить его отправлять картинки. Документация на официальном сайти не помогла!

Код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import vk_api, time, bs4, random, requests

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token='')

values = {'out':0, 'count': 100, 'time_offset': 60}
vk.method('messages.GetConverstion', values)

def send_msg(user_id, s):
    vk.method('messages.Send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': s})

while True:
    response = vk.method('messages.getConversation')

    if response['items'] and response['items'][0]['last_messgae']['from_id']>0:
       response=response['items'][0]

    if response['last_message']['text'].lower()=='привет' or response['last_message']['text'].lower()=='приветик':
        send_msg(response['conversation']['peer']['id'], 'Дратуте. Для всех команд напиши !Команды')
```

Comment: примеры кода в студию

Comment: В документации всё есть https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=4.%2B%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%2B%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%2B%D0%B2%2B%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%2B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: А пример загрузки картинки для питона есть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734002) (хотя используется другая ВК-библиотека, но нетрудно адаптировать под vk_api)

Answer (score 1):

во 1-х я бы посоветовал вам не "извращать" уже написанную библиотеку - отправлять сообшения так: 
`vk.method("messages.send"{"bla-bla-bla":"bla-bla-bla"})`
А чтобы отправить медиавложение, отправляйте его, передав параметр `"attachment" :"my_attachment".`